# Show a UIPopover on Tab Bar Controller buttons/icons

Tags: ios7, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5, uipopovercontroller

My app using a Tab Bar Controller using storyboards.  During the first time through the app, I want to use a UIPoppver on each of the Tab Bar buttons.  However, to do this, I need to know the CGRect for each (I think).  How do I go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the frame of a particular tab bar item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325457/getting-the-frame-of-a-particular-tab-bar-item)

Comment: Thanks, how do I reference my TabBarController, as it's hooked up using storyboards, and no code?

Answer (score 0):

here is how I solved this, thanks to the link provided above:

In my AppDelegate.h

Added:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)tabBarMutableArray;
```

In my AppDelegate.m

Added:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)tabBarMutableArray;
{
    UITabBarController *tabController           = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    NSMutableArray     *tabBarItemsMutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    UITabBar *tabBar = tabController.tabBar;

    for (UIView *view in tabBar.subviews)
    {
        [tabBarItemsMutableArray addObject:view.description];
    }

    return  tabBarItemsMutableArray;
}
```

Now I can access the value anywhere with this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"Array AppDelegate: %@", [appDelegate tabBarMutableArray]);
```

Results:

```
"<_UITabBarBackgroundView: 0x145e19f70; frame = (0 0; 1024 56); autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1700359c0>>",
"<UITabBarButton: 0x145e15950; frame = (254 1; 76 55); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17002a9a0>>",
"<UITabBarButton: 0x145e19dd0; frame = (364 1; 76 55); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1700345c0>>",
"<UITabBarButton: 0x145d0f8a0; frame = (474 1; 76 55); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17803cc60>>",
"<UITabBarButton: 0x145e1a360; frame = (584 1; 76 55); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1700348e0>>",
"<UITabBarButton: 0x145e1a940; frame = (694 1; 76 55); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x170034c60>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x145e1a090; frame = (0 -0.5; 1024 0.5); autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1700369e0>>"
```